# Django with python3, results of sql query in selectbox

Tags: python, sql, django

I have 2 models:

```
PR_Components (models.Model):
   companyID = models.ForeignKey(PO_Company, blank=True, null=True)
   comp_nr = models.CharField (max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comp_nr

PR_ComponentsData (models.Model):
    compID = models.ForeignKey (PR_Components, blank=False, null=True)
    valid = models.DateField (max_length=10, blank=False, null=True)
    comp_image = models.ImageField (upload_to="/images", blank=True, null=True)
    comp_text = models.CharField (max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)
    ....
```

I want to show now in a selectbox the components number (PR_Components.comp_nr) and their current valid name (PR_Componentsdata.comp_text).

I added a manager to model PR_Components which executes a sql-query.

```
SELECT a.*, b1.* FROM pool_pr_components a 
JOIN pool_pr_componentsdata b1 ON (a.id =  b1.compID_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pool_pr_componentsdata b2 
ON (a.id = b2.compID__id AND (b1.valid < b2.valid OR b1.valid = b2.valid    
AND b1.id < b2.id)) WHERE b2.id IS NULL
```

Later I write forms dynamicly and add the sql-result to the field:

```
self.fields[field].queryset = sql_result
```

Until here, everything works fine.

My problem:
In the selectbox the result of the **str**-Method of model PR_Components is shown (=comp_nr), but I would like to show also the component name like "Component (001)".

How could I do this? It should be a solution which works for other models too, because a lot of my models have "historical" data.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
in model PR_Components we overwrite **str** with

```
def __str__(self):
    related = PR_ComponentsData.objects.filter(id=self.id).last()
    return "{} ({})".format (related.comp_text, self.comp_nr)
```